# How do I convert a datetime field to a formatted string in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to SELECT a formatted date string from a `datetime` type in SQL Server 2005.

In the format "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss".

What is the best way to do using only a query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the CONVERT statement.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), getdate(), 120)
```

is closest to what you want.  (Note the different separators (- instead of / ))

Answer (score 3):

```
 select convert(varchar, datetime_field, 120) from tablename;
```

will do *almost* what you want.

`120` is the conversion "style", [see here for more.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450.aspx)